# WPF: Is there workaround when value multiplies itself by 10 when backspacing over decimal point

Tags: c#, wpf

I am running into this really odd issue when binding to a decimal value any time I backspace over the decimal point the bound value (and the displayed value) get multiplied by 10.

Essentially if I have the cursor to the right of decimal point `55.|0` hit `Backpace` I would expect to get `5|.5` however instead I get `550|.0`

Is there a workaround for this issue to allow `Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` behavior and decimal points being entered? (`PropertyChanged` is truly the desired behavior for me in this case, `LostFocus` is not a very good option for me)

```
<Window x:Class="SandboxWpf.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:sandboxWpf="clr-namespace:SandboxWpf"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
        <Window.DataContext>
            <sandboxWpf:MainViewModel/>
        </Window.DataContext>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding MyVal, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, StringFormat=N1}"></TextBox>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

--

```
   namespace SandboxWpf
    {
        public class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

            [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
            protected virtual void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
            {
                PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
                if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        public class MainViewModel : ObservableObject
        {
            private double _myVal;

            public MainViewModel()
            {
                MyVal = 55.0;
            }

            public double MyVal
            {
                get { return _myVal; }
                set
                {
                    RaisePropertyChanged();
                    _myVal = value;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Edit: 
Ended up going with a 'string' work around, works out well just have to remember to convert everything to double before using '+' operator.

Comment: `OneWayToSource` might work for you.

Comment: `OneWayToSource` fixes the issue of multiplication by 10, however, I have a datagrid in the same view which is editable and is bound to the same elements so if I set the `TextBox` using `OneWayToSource` I will have lots of stale data.

Comment: The work around I am currently thinking of doing is exposing string `MyValStr` properties for these values and doing the conversion myself in the view model (I would really like to avoid that though)

Comment: masked text box could help you better here.

Comment: Assuming you can create a workaround, what if the user actually _wants_ to delete the decimal point? How would they do it?

Comment: With a string workaround if you delete the decimal point you go from '12.|34' to '1234' even though that is not ideal it is more intuitive than going from '12.|34' 'to '120.24'. To get rid of this issue we can just compare during the set whether we are going from previous value(12.|34) to a value that is one with decimal point taken out(1234) while having values to the right of decimal point(.34) in which case we do not remove decimal point but remove value to the left of decimal (res 1|.34), if there is nothing to the right of decimal '12.|' we allow removal of the decimal point (res '12|').